# Good HTML5page designing for cross platform mobile webView(s)

Tags: html, webview

What HTML5 tags best suited to build this mobile web app which needs to runs inside webViews of various smartphone platforms "iOS, Android, Window, ..." ?

The title in the middle of the header will change, The label and number of buttons on the footer will change, the content in the middle will have many data input controls (textfields, radio groups,...)  so needs to scroll vertically but with the header and footer fixed. The side navigator shows up at initial start and can slide out with a swipe gesture or by hitting the top left`☰`  menu button.

Thank you

[image]

Is something like this best suited?

```html
   <body>
     <section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
       <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Activity</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-content">
         <p>This is the content on page 1</p>
         <!-- put some kind of a table with cells here -->
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
         <!-- Buttons go here -->
      </div>
   </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is a good representation of it:

```
<body>
     <section id="firstpage" data-role="page">
       <div data-role="header">
         <h1>Activity</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-content">
         <p>This is the content on page 1</p>
         <!-- put some kind of a table with cells here -->
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
         <!-- Buttons go here -->
      </div>
   </section>
<section id="secondpage" data-role="page">
       <div data-role="header">
         <h1>label2</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="ui-content">
         <p>This is the content on page 1</p>
         <!-- put some kind of a table with cells here -->
      </div>
      <div data-role="footer">
         <!-- Buttons go here -->
      </div>
   </section>
</body>
```